# Wygwam field with sub-domains - Can't insert media from YouTube

Tags: ee2, wygwam, subdomain, embed-media

ExpressionEngine v2.7.1 - Build Date: 20130924
Wygwam 3.1.2

If I create a new entry, I am able to click on the "Embed Media" button in the toolbar and paste the YouTube provided embed code, click "Save" and the video inserts without issue.

However, if I edit that entry, or edit another entry and attempt to insert a video in another location, I click the "Embed Media" button in the toolbar and paste the YouTube provided embed code, click "Save" and nothing happens.

In the console window, (Chrome), I get the following:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://admin.domain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://domain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.        ckeditor.js:876
```

In IE script error window I get:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.        ckeditor.js, line 876 character 99
```

I don't understand why it works the first go, but not the edit.

Comment: Does this happen in all of your browsers? I recall something about this being a Chrome issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It happens in all browsers. The first error was the Chrome error and the second one was the IE error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to an error being triggered from the frame being used on NSM Live Look and permission settings. When I disabled the NSM Live Look add-on, everything worked smoothly. I am trying to resolve this issue further by seeing if there is something I can do with the NSM Live Look scripts, but I haven't received any responses from the developer yet.